# Как автоматическии сохранять раннее веденные тексты и при перезагрузки чтобы текст оставался на месте?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
<body>
  <form onsubmit="javascript:return false; " id="form">
    
        <input class="text" placeholder="Написать...">
            
        <button class="math" onclick="display()">Отправить</button>
        
        </form>   
        





        <script>
        
        function display() {
            let txt = document.querySelector(".text");
            let show = document.createElement('p')
            show.classList.add('.show')
            let value = txt.value
            if(value!="") {
                show.innerText=value + '' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() 
                document.body.append(show)
                  form.reset()
            }
        } 
         
        
        </script>
```

Comment: в session/localStorage записывай. при перезагрузке выводи, что там есть

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```js
const key = `my-text`;
const $textarea = document.querySelector(`textarea`);
$textarea.value = localStorage.getItem(key) || ``;

$textarea.addEventListener(`input`, e => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```